# Expected undefined to be a GraphQL leaf type

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I am getting the following error when running relay-compiler in my project

```
$ get-graphql-schema http://localhost/api/office > schema.graphql   
$ relay-compiler --src ./src/client --schema schema.graphql  
Watchman:  Watchman was not found in PATH.  See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html for installation instructions  
HINT: pass --watch to keep watching for changes.  

Writing js  
ERROR:  
Expected undefined to be a GraphQL leaf type.  
error Command failed with exit code 100.
```

Any suggestions on how to go about debugging this, the only recent change  in my project (famous last words) was upgrading to relay 1.5. I suspect it is something in the graphql schema that needs to change to fit within the new relay-compiler, but I am not seeing it.

The schema.graphql is below:

```
schema {
  query: RootQuery
  mutation: RootMutation
}

type Delete {
  n: String
  nModified: String
  ok: String
}

type Room {
  _uuid: String
  roomName: String
  serviceName: String
  roomURL: String
  roomID: String
  phoneNumber1: String
  phoneNumber2: String
  participantCode: String
  moderatorCode: String
  video: String
  otherLink1: String
  otherLink2: String
  color: String
}

# Mutation interface
type RootMutation {
  createRoom(
    # Name of the room owner
    ownerName: String

    # Email of the room owner
    ownerEmail: String!

    # Name of the room
    roomName: String!

    # Service name
    serviceName: String!

    # URL
    roomURL: String!

    # ID to meeting room
    roomID: String

    # Phone number 1
    phoneNumber1: String!

    # Phone number 2
    phoneNumber2: String

    # Participant code
    participantCode: String!

    # Moderator code
    moderatorCode: String!

    # Video
    video: String

    # Color
    color: String
  ): Room
  deleteRoom(
    # Email of the room owner
    ownerEmail: String!

    # Name of the room
    roomName: String!
  ): Delete
}

type RootQuery {
  meetingsUser(ownerEmail: String!, _uuid: String, refetch: Boolean): [User]
}

type User {
  _id: String
  ownerEmail: String
  ownerName: String

  # Provides a list of all rooms owned by the user
  rooms: Room
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you are missing global id field on your type.

I had the same issue, but adding

```
type MyType = {
  id: ID
   ...
}
```

solved the problem.

See also https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1880#issuecomment-307705428

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks.